# How to undo /revert "heroku git:clone"

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone, undo, heroku-cli

I try to clone one project from heroku using the command

```
heroku git:remote -a projectname
```

But i cloned the project in wrong folder.

How can i undo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is just so great that you just have to **move or rename** your directory. Everything is stored in .git subdirectory

Moving a directory depends on your system and your habits. In Linux / MacOSX terminal, you could simply do

```
mv sourcedir targetdir
```

Or, if you use any file explore, simply drag and drop your fresh folder to where you want it to be.

Comment: how can i do it. any example